# How uninstall GitHub CLI in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, github

i installed GitHub CLI like written here https://www.techiediaries.com/install-github-cli-ubuntu-20/ :

#### install

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key C99B11DEB97541F0
sudo apt-add-repository https://cli.github.com/packages
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gh
```

#### uninstall

i read howto uninstall it other systems here:

https://github.com/cli/cli

for example `spack uninstall gh`

and tried with this error:

```
sudo apt uninstall gh
E: Invalid operation uninstall
```

how to fix it?

Comment: How did you install it? Please edit the question to add that information.

Comment: Read `man apt`.

Comment: @waltinator `sudo apt remove gh` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @waltinator said above, this works:

`sudo apt remove gh`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [nala](https://github.com/volitank/nala), and simply type:

```
sudo nala remove gh
```